# How to prevent CodeMirror to remove html tags

Tags: html, wordpress, editor

I've recently been using a module for WordPress, which uses CodeMirror as a WYSIWYG editor. I noticed that it removes the ,  and <!DOCTYPE> tags. How can this problem be solved? I am also attaching some print screens.
[image]

[image]
[image]